# Issues with measurement performance in AWS when measurement times change

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-ec2, requests-per-second

This is the model we set up to measure performance (tps value). The client will send a number of requests from small to large (maximum 3000 requests at a time) to the server. Performance is calculated by the number of requests the server can process in a fixed period of time.
Question:
Also with this model, in December 2022 we measured tps in the range of 550 ~ 600. However, in December 2023 we measured tps always < 500. Note that EC2 instance type, EC2 OS , server code and client code remain the same.
Currently we have not found a way to detect the cause, can you give me any ideas or information to find out what the problem is?

[aws architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jezo0.png)

Can find the factor impact to performance value